# Managing edit queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many times when I am editing a post, someone else is also doing it at the same time. Since my changes are not there, we are effectively editing same contents. And who so ever finishes first, will be able to submit. Other person's time and effort is wasted since he won't be able to submit until the previous edits are approved.

Could we implement some kind of lock so that this effort and time could be saved?

Comment: how does it work? If the lock is implemented, should I be seeing a warning before I start editing or when I am going to save the changes?

Comment: @nhahtdh, as far as I know, "edit" is only locked one suggested edit has been submitted and pending for approval. At that point even 2k users can't edit the post without going through Suggested Edit Review.

Comment: @nhahtdh: may be, but the point is that I don't think there is 'edit lock' *before first edit is submitted*. At this point other edits-in-progress will be notified by bar appearing at top of the screen that there has been another edit to the same post you are editing.

Comment: @vhu if that is implemented, I suppose there is a bug. I sometimes see that bar, but sometimes I get that error only once I try to submit my changes.

Comment: @vhu: OK, I'll remove my comments, since I'm talking about something completely different. There is no such mechanism for the case you mention, and I don't think SO will implement it, since it doesn't solve any problem (people who comes in during the lock period can't edit, and they will leave instead).

Comment: @vhu they will leave to other questions, and continue editing there.

Comment: @nhahtdh, you may have misunderstood me here, I'm not requesting such functionality much less endorsing it. I just state that it doesn't exist and that's probably the reason why OP ends up in edit races with others.